# C# Todas as minha comboBox estão mudando de text

Tags: c#, combobox, text

Estou tendo um problema com meu programa em que quando eu mudo os valores de uma de minhas *comboBox*, exemplo:

```
private void Ex1Mat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (start == false)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter Ex1UpdateAss = new SqlDataAdapter("select Assunto, id from dbo.Assuntos where Materia = " + Ex1Mat.Text + "", conex);
        Ex1UpdateAss.Fill(AssTable);
        Ex1Ass.DataSource = AssTable;
        Ex1Ass.DisplayMember = AssTable.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        Ex1Ass.ValueMember = AssTable.Columns[1].ColumnName;
    }
}
```

todas mudam seus `DisplayMembers` o que no caso era para mudar apenas uma.

Tem ideia do que seja isso?

Comment: Você tem várias combobox na sua tela e quando chama o selectedindexchanged todas mudam também ? (outras combos?)  é isso?

Answer (score 1):

É possivel que você tenha selecionado todas as ComboBoxes acidentalmente ao criar o evento. Neste caso o VisualStudio atrela o código do evento que deveria estar em uma única combobox a todas as que estavam selecionadas no momento. Para ter cetteza, será necessario o código  Designer.cs do form em questão. Dê uma olhada pra ver se o evento SelectIndexChanged de todas elas estão apontando pro mesmo método.